# Why is $S$ specified to be nonempty in Axler’s definition of function spaces $\mathbf F^S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

In Example 1.24 of S. Axler’s *Linear Algebra Done Right*, the following statement is made:

> If $S$ is a nonempty set, then $\mathbf F^S$ […] is a vector space over $\mathbf F$.

(Here, $\mathbf F^S$ is the set of functions from $S$ to $\mathbf F$, and $\mathbf F$ is either $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.)

However, this statement is true even if $S=\varnothing$. (Then there is only *one* function $S \to \mathbf F$, and $\mathbf F^S$ is trivial.) Why would Axler have written *nonempty*? Is he simply distracting from “weird” corner cases for didactic purposes, or is there some deeper motivation?

Comment: I should note that it’s nowhere said that $S$ *can’t* be empty, so it’s not an *error* – but it does seem like an unnecessary specification. Also, he does the same when defining $\mathbf F^n$: there, $n$ is fixed to be “positive”, whereas $\mathbf F^0$ is a perfectly fine vector space. How strange.

Comment: This would be the least ridiculous thing Axler does "for didactic purposes" :)

Comment: It seems to me that this is a dubious pedagogical choice if you want to avoid thinking about "weird" cases, given that specifying that $S$ is nonempty actually draws attention to the case when $S$ is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Example 1.24 of *Linear Algebra Done Right* (3rd edition), I considered $\mathbf{F}^S$ only for nonempty sets $S$ because it is unusual to think about a function whose domain is the empty set. I did not want to distract the reader with that issue when there are more important things for the reader to think about in the context of learning about $\mathbf{F}^S$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up! As Eric Wofsey wrote in his comment on my question, though, your intention backfired: I was helping a friend through the start of your book, and she was distracted precisely by the use of the word *nonempty* – if you’d just written *a set*, I doubt we’d have considered the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason ought to be your first, that is avoiding the corner case.

There is no reason I can think of for not considering  $F^{\emptyset}$ as a (trivial) vector space. Indeed, to truly exclude it would be inconvenient.

But, in the context I can see the point to not ask for the argument. It is one of those things that  could trip up somebody. Generally, I try to avoid such questions, too. (Or if not, I hint at the fact there is a corner case.)