# Can empty set be an additive identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Reading linear algebra done right 3rd edition.

For $R$, concerning about empty set as additive identity probably does not make sense.

Though for \texttt{sum of subsets}, its definition is $$ U_1 + \dots + U_m = \{u_1 + \dots + u_m : u_i \in U_i \} $$

With this definition, it seems $U_1 + \emptyset$ is a valid addition operation, which is an addition simply without elements from other $u_i$.

I know this understanding is wrong. After all, if the above claim is true then $\emptyset$ would be an additive identity to any subspace. That is in contradiction with the fact that each subspace should only have one unique additive identity.

What do I miss?

**Update:**

As a reference, checkout the definition of "sum of subsets". it explicitly says "subsets", rather than "non-empty subsets", or "subspaces". Does that imply this definition allows empty set?

[image]

Comment: The addition operation on subspaces (or subsets) is not the same as the addition operation on vectors within subspaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition,
$$ 
    U_1 + \emptyset = \{u_1 + u_2 : u_1 \in U_1, u_2 \in \emptyset\}.
$$
But there *are* no sums $u_1 + u_2$ where $u_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2 \in \emptyset$, because it's impossible to choose $u_2 \in \emptyset$. Therefore, $U_1 + \emptyset = \emptyset$. This is not what an additive identity does!

(Also, the sum $U_1 + \emptyset$ is not interesting in the context of linear algebra, because $\emptyset$ is not a vector space. But the addition of sets is defined in other settings too, so it's not wrong to ask what $U_1 + \emptyset$ is: you just don't get an interesting answer.)

Comment: If there is nothing to choose from $\emptyset$, shouldn't the sum just equal $U_1$?

Comment: Thanks. if that is the case, while Aler defines "sum of subsets" as "suppose $U_1,\dots, U_m$" are subsets of V ...", why doesn't he just claim "... are non-empty sets of $V$"?  I assumed the definition was done with a purpose (i.e. allowing elements to be empty sets).

Comment: Oh yeah, got confused with that. Thanks!

Comment: @Seeker The sum would equal $U_1$ if there were a way to write every element of $U_1$ in the form $u_1 + u_2$ where $u_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2 \in \emptyset$. But there is no such way to do it.

Comment: @RuoyunHuang The sum of sets can be defined in general, even if the sets are empty, it just is not as interesting in such cases.

Comment: @Seeker I have the same confusion.  Even though Misha's argument does hold from convenience perspective. I am still confused b/c there is NO prior definition in the book, which makes one understanding valid versus the other isn't.   Math is supposed to rigorous after all.  Yeah, I accept this answer for now, even though it is still not comletely clear to me.    Thanks Misha.

Comment: @RoyHuang If you go a few pages back you will find the definition of $F^S$. Namely, the set of all functions from $S$ to $F$. In this definition, Axler doesn’t specify whether the set is empty or non-empty. Someone even asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733562/why-is-s-specified-to-be-nonempty-in-axler-s-definition-of-function-spaces-m/1734275#1734275)  and received an answer by Sheldon Axler himself. I think the reason he gave there is the same reason for this. He just wanted students to focus on linear algebra rather than corner cases.

Comment: @RoyHuang But it is good to look at corner cases as well. He even mentions after the proof of the “linear dependence lemma” that the book will not call attention to such corner cases.